# How can the shortest path between two nodes in a balanced binary tree be affected by path 'weight'?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, shortest-path

I am following an online introductory algorithms course with Udacity.

In the final assessment there is a question as follows:

> In the shortest-path oracle described in Andrew Goldberg's interview,
>   each node has a label, which is a list of some other nodes in the
>   network and their distance to these nodes.  These lists have the
>   property that:
>
> (1) for any pair of nodes (x,y) in the network, their lists will have
>   at least one node z in common
>
> (2) the shortest path from x to y will go through z.   Given a graph G
>   that is a balanced binary tree, preprocess the graph to create such
>   labels for each node.  Note that the size of the list in each label
>   should not be larger than log n for a graph of size n.

[The full question can be found here.](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs215/l-48734363/e-722588594/m-48717293)

Given the constraint of a balanced binary tree and the hint that the size should not be larger than log n, intuitively it seems that the label for a particular node would consist of all its parents (and optionally itself, if it isn't a leaf).

However some additional instructor notes in the question adds:

> Write your solution to work on weighted graphs. Note that the test
>   given, all the edges have a weight of one - which isn't particularly
>   interesting.

So my question is:

**How can the shortest path between two nodes in a binary tree be affected by whether the paths have weights or not?**

Surely in a binary tree, the shortest path between two nodes is the unique simple path, and is unaffected by any weighting?
(unless weights can be negative and the path doesn't have to be simple in which case there is no shortest path?)

My basic solution works with the simple test provided in the question, but fails to pass the automatic grader which gives no feedback.

I'm obviously misunderstanding something, but what...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think my initial reaction and the obvious answer is correct:

Positive weights **cannot** affect the **shortest path** between two nodes in a binary tree.

On the other hand, weights obviously **do** affect the **shortest 'distance'** between two nodes in a binary tree as compared to simply calculating 'distance' between nodes as the number of hops.

This is what the udacity instruction was getting at. 
It seems that this instruction to work with weighted binary trees was simply to enable correct automatic grading of the code which relied on using the labels to calculate the exact shortest '**distance**' (which is affected by weight) as opposed to the shortest **path** (list of nodes) which is not.

Once I modified my algorithm to take this into account and output the correct distance, it passed the grader.